# Requirements for base PIC test

Tags: pic

I am very new to PIC programming. I have PIC12F675 and I was just wondering if I need something else than connecting MCLR to VDD for it to work. As I understand extra components are not necessary for it?

For start I just want to toggle output every second:

```
void main()
{
     TRISIO = 0;
     while(1)
     {
             GPIO = 0;
             delay_ms(1000);
             GPIO = 1;
             delay_ms(1000);
     }
}
```

In mikroC I use these parameters:
[image]

For uploading hex I use K150 programmer. I read the MCU memory and it seems uploading works. Then I put it on breadboard with 10kOhm resistor (MCLR->VDD).

When I connect 5.26V to it, it uses ~130uA for ~5s and then stays stable at 40uA.
I do not notice any output voltage changes on any GPIO (check with voltmeter-multimeter). What am I doing wrong?

Here are the oscillator choices:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have selected an RC oscillator as the clock source, but have not connected one, so the PIC has no clock and therefore will not run.

Comment: Which one should I choose? INTOSC?

Comment: I don't know what options you have. Selecting an internal oscillator sounds like a good idea.

Comment: I added extra photo

Comment: So I can use internal without any extra parts, right?

Comment: You choose whatever option you want to use. The options should be explained in the data sheet.

Comment: I chose the second - it works! Tahnks.

Comment: You might also need to configure the pins from analog to digital I/O, using "ANSEL=0", but apparently it works without this, or perhaps you have not shown all the code. Perhaps MikroC takes care of that automatically. It does differ from MPLABX and XC8, which I use.